# PHP functiom, default return echo OR return value

Tags: php

I got PHP function like this:

```
function doingSomething($arg)
{
    ...
    echo($someString);
}
```

I don't want to copy/pase that function and make second one only if I need that function to return value, not echo it. How could I modify it so it will just return $someString whenever I need it?

Comment: If I add return it will do both. I just want to do "return" whenever I need insted of "echo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another parameter to tell your function what to do with the string:

```
function doingSomething($someString, $echo = false){
    if($echo){
      echo $someString;
    } 
    return $someString;
}
```

Then if you want to echo it:

```
doingSomething('String to echo', true);
```

Or return:

```
doingSomething('String to return');
```

Comment: Why not always return the string, but only echo it if there's a parameter set?

Comment: Because that's not what the OP asked?

Comment: @ScottHelme It doesn't matter if it returns anything or not if it's just called by `doingSomething('string')` any way.

Comment: Thanks anOG. Can it work like if I just put one arg in that function (I won't put second arg in that function) it will echo by default and if I put second arg: false it will return it?

Comment: I would have thought that the original would have made it a little easier to understand.

Comment: @DanielFukuda I've added an optional parameter. Simply change `$echo = false` to `$echo = true` to have `true` be the default if nothing has been specified.

Comment: Glad to have helped - Props to @h2ooooooo

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a second parameter to the function.

```
function doSomething($arg, $doOutput) {
    ...
    if ($doOutput) { echo $someString; }
    else { return $someString; }
}
```

This will echo the String if $doOutput is true and return it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just either use or return the value as needed like this:

```
<?php
function doingSomething()
{
    return "Fluffeh";
}

$var=doingSomething();
echo $var."<br><br>";

echo "Or this way ".doingSomething();
?>
```

You get the best of both worlds, can either save the output into a variable or simply echo it out in your code as needed?

Output:

```
Fluffeh

Or this way Fluffeh
```

Comment: By default I will echo, only in very rare cases I will return it so I will save space by doing echo in that function by default.

Comment: The only other way is as the other two answers suggest, which is to pass another argument to the function each and every time. On that note though, saving space? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes I already got answer made by anOG and that is was I was looking for. As for saving space... well I will be calling that function with HTML code so it's easier for me to just put that function (without echo before it, and no, I don't want to save that function's String to another $var) so I know it will echo string... nevermind it's all good now :) Thanks to you all!